# Extract text from PDFbox

Tags: java, ocr, pdfbox, tess4j

I have two similar sample ticket, in that one ticket is reading horizontal and other one vertical.

| 1st image | 2nd image |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 1st image] | [image: 2nd image] |

In 1st image result is

```
BOOKING ID : BBT3001402 

HI ! YOUR BOOKING AT​ MATHURA EXECUTIVE​ IS CONFIRMED! 

CHECK IN 
31 
JANUARY 
FRIDAY 
NIGHTS 
4N 

CHECK OUT 
4 
FEBRUARY 
TUESDAY 
BOOKING DETAILS:
```

2nd image result

```
BOOKING ID : BBT2601540
HI ! YOUR BOOKING AT VIVANTA BENGALURU, RESIDENCY ROAD IS CONFIRMED!
CHECK IN NIGHTS CHECK OUT
27 7N 03
JANUARY FEBRUARY
WEDNESDAY WEDNESDAY
BOOKING DETAILS:
```

I want PDFbox to read data in any one fixed format (horizontal/Vertical).

Comment: try setting the sort option, if you did use PDFBox, your question doesn't tell whether you used PDFBox or tesseract or both.

Comment: Indeed, this might be solved by activating sorting. Unfortunately only bitmap images, not the original PDFs, are attached here, so we can only assume...

Comment: If the pdf format is predetermined then I would just chop it off accordingly and use a specific psm for each to find out the text.

Answer (score 0):

PDFBox is for pdf manipulation and it doesn't do OCR out of the box, you need something like ApacheTika or Tesseract OCR

if the pdf already has text in it you can extract it like this

```
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    stripper.setStartPage(1); // 1 based
    stripper.setEndPage(1);
    String extractedText = stripper.getText(doc);
    System.out.println(extractedText);
```

Comment: Most likely this is exactly what the OP currently does and what results in differently arranged texts in the output...